# insertInto output returns '?' instead of real value

Tags: java, jooq

I am looking for a way to generate SQL queries in different dialects. I found out that probably best for it is tool/library jOOQ.

After calling this line of code:

```
System.out.println(ctx.insertInto(DSL.table(DSL.name("table"))).set(DSL.field("id"), 1).getSQL());
```

I have a problem with with the output:

```
insert into table (id) values (?)
```

Why is there '?' instead of number 1?

I expected:

```
insert into table (id) values (1)
```

And I also have a question how to generate SQL as strings, should I rather create a real database and somehow get whole SQL of table? Is it possible to gain whole SQL queries which I used/called before or I it will be better to always use getSQL() only?

Comment: You should really ask separate questions for those last two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the SQL you get is what jOOQ would actually use when it passes the statement to the JDBC, [`1` is passed as a bound value instead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps). This is safer and more efficient in many cases, not just in JDBC but in other similar APIs.

But for this use-case, [the documentation says](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/)

> Sometimes, you may wish to avoid rendering bind variables while still using custom values in SQL. jOOQ refers to that as "inlined" bind values. When bind values are inlined, they render the actual value in SQL rather than a JDBC question mark. Bind value inlining can be achieved in several ways:
>
> - Globally, by using the Settings and setting the org.jooq.conf.StatementType to STATIC_STATEMENT. This will inline all bind values for SQL statements rendered from such a Configuration.
> - Per query locally, by using the Query.getSQL(ParamType) method.
> - Per value locally, by using DSL.inline() methods.

For this specific case I expect calling `getSQL(ParamType.INLINED)` instead of just `getSQL()` to work as well, just from looking at [the API](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/Query.html).